# Make Aside Stretch To Be Same Height As Section With Heading and Article

Tags: html, css

The aside only stretches to the height of the article. How can I make it stretch all the way to the top of the section, which includes the header?

```css
section {
  border-style: inset;
  border-color: #ffe4d1;
}

article {
  width: 70%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48em;
}

aside {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12em;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h3>What It Is</h3>
  <article>
    <p>TEXT</p>
    <p>TEXT</p>
  </article>
  <aside>
    <img class="cover" src="images/self-image.jpg" scale="" />
  </aside>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout) as such:

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 70% auto;
}

h3 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 128, .15);
  margin: 0;
}

article {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, .15);
}

aside {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
  background-color: rgba(128, 0, 0, .15);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h3>h3</h3>
  <article>
    article
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <p>paragraph</p>
  </article>
  <aside>
    aside
  </aside>
</section>
```